# Postgresql: Delimited text to json?

Tags: json, postgresql, csv

There is one text column in the table in delimited text format (comma separated):
34,45,566,663....

It takes too long to update those columns ( for example, delete or add an element). For some reasons,  there is no option to convert or change that column type.

What is the fastest way to edit comma separated text ?

Comment: regexp_split_to_array(text, ',')  ?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why don't you make a separate table for this one-to-many relationship?

Comment: this column represents the order of numbers , according to project architecture I cannot change the format, because it will require some hardware rewrite. what I need is to optimize update queries

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid non-formated fields allways.
JSON o XML have specific functions to access and index them Text is a cat-bag (blob)